# How to create array in if statement

Tags: sas

I'd like to replicate and modify specific rows in the table.

before:

```
xyz_id | letter | Col_1 | ...|
1 | Z | V1 | ... |
2 | Z | V2 | ... |
3 | Z | V3 | ... |
```

after:

```
xyz_id | letter | Col_1 | ...|
1 | A | V1.1 | ... |
1 | B | V1.2 | ... |
1 | C | V1.3 | ... |
2 | A | V2.1 | ... |
2 | B | V2.2 | ... |
2 | C | V2.3 | ... |
3 | A | V3.1 | ... |
3 | B | V3.2 | ... |
3 | C | V3.3 | ... |
```

I've prepared the following code:

```
data test2;
        set test;

        
        array letters {3} $3 _temporary_ ('A', 'B', 'C');
        array weights {3}  _temporary_ (1,2,3);

/*      if xyz_id = '1' */
/*          then  array weights {3}  _temporary_ (1,2,3);*/
/*      else if xyz_id = '2'*/
/*          then array weights {3}  _temporary_ (8,7,6);*/
/*      else array weights {3}  _temporary_ (1,1,1)*/


        do i = 1 to 8;
            letter = letters(i);
            Col_A = Col_A * weights(i);
            output;
        end;
          drop i;
run;
```

Now, I'm trying to make *weights* depend of the *letter* column (commented code) - but without any success. I also tried:

```
   array weights_1 {3}  _temporary_ (1,2,3);
   if xyz_id = '1'
            then  weights = weights_1;
```

but it didn't work as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
data have;
input xyz_id letter  $ Col_1 $;
datalines;
1 Z V1 
2 Z V2 
3 Z V3 
;

data want;
  set have;

  array letters {3} $3 _temporary_ ('A', 'B', 'C');
  array weights {3}    _temporary_ (1,2,3);

  c = Col_1;

  do i = 1 to 3;
      letter = letters[i];
      Col_1  = catx('.', c, weights[i]);
      output;
  end;
  
  drop i c;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add an 3D array.

```
array weights{3,3}  
                            c1_w1-c1_w8
                            c2_w1-c2_w8
                            c3_w1-c3_w8 
                                (
                                0.1 0.1   /*letter 1*/
                                1 22 23   /*letter 2*/
                                1 32 33   /*letter 3*/
                                );
```

so the final codes is:

```
data test2;
        set test;

        
        array letters {3} $3 _temporary_ ('A', 'B', 'C');
        array weights {3}  _temporary_ (1,2,3);



            if xyz_id = '1' 
                then  weights_dim=1;
            else if xyz_id = '2' 
                then  weights_dim=2;
            else if xyz_id = '3' 
                then  weights_dim=3;

        weight = weights{weights_dim, i};

        do i = 1 to 8;


            letter = letters(i);
            Col_A = Col_A * weight;
            output;
        end;
          drop i;
run;
```